# Javascript errors when calling

Tags: javascript

I have read and tried everything I can think of.  The other pages that look identical with calling the function onclick work fine.  I have tried all I know and read extensively with no avail.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Password</title>
</head>

    <body>

        <div id="output"></div>
        <input id="playername" placeholder = "Username" /> <br>
        <input id="password" placeholder = "Enter Password"/>
        <button onclick="test()">Are you correct?</button>
        <script src="pword.js"></script>    
    </body>
```

JS:

```
function test() {

    let output = document.querySelector("#output");
    let playername = document.querySelector("#playername");
    let password = document.querySelector("#password");

    if output.value === ("username") && password.value === ("Pa$$w0rd") {  
        console.log("CORRECT!");
    } else {
        console.log("Incorrect, try again");
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the error? Can you provide a stack trace? The error message? Or at least the type of error?

Comment: The `if` statement in your `test()` function is incorrect; it's missing the parentheses around the expression.

Comment: I am sorry, this is the error ReferenceError: test is not defined

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but Is the JS included on the page with the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a bracket during your if statement

```
if HERE => ( output.value === ("username") && password.value === ("Pa$$w0rd") ) <= AND HERE {  
    console.log("CORRECT!");
} else {
    console.log("Incorrect, try again");
}
```

And it's better to do something like this, remove you'r onclick on HTML and do this :

### HTML :

```
<button id="MyButton">Are you correct?</button>
```

### JS :

```
var MyBtn = document.getElementById("MyButton");
MyBtn.addEventListener("click", test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (playername.value === "username" && password.value === "Pa$$w0rd") {  
    console.log("CORRECT!");
} else {
    console.log("Incorrect, try again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `output.value` instead of `playername.value` and the parenthesis are misplaced, here's a snippet with fixed code :

```js
function test() {
  let output = document.querySelector("#output");
  let playername = document.querySelector("#playername");
  let password = document.querySelector("#password");

  if (playername.value === "username" && password.value === "Pa$$w0rd") {
    console.log("CORRECT!");
  } else {
    console.log("Incorrect, try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="playername" placeholder="Username" /> <br>
<input id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
<button onclick="test()">Are you correct?</button>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you all so much for the help, it will help me see mistakes to hopefully not make in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `output.value` instead of `playername.value`.

You can have a look at the working code here: https://repl.it/repls/ImaginaryCandidPerformance